# How do I change the email address associated with previous git commits?

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to change the email address associated with my previous git commits so I can record and maintain my previous contributions on the GitHub chart so how can I do that?

I have tried many solutions but have been unable to solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the author and committer name/email for multiple commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-and-committer-name-email-for-multiple-commits)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure that your GitHub account is associated with your commits then it’s easier to just add the old email that you were using to your GitHub account.

Settings → Emails → Add

[image: Settings: Emails]